# How to filter date greater than a current date and less than current date in Yii Gridview filter

Tags: gridview, yii, datepicker

I'm creating an application where I have 2 buttons namely : `Past` and `Present`. 
For this I'm using **Advanced Search** form, in which I created buttons `Past` and `Present` out of the field called `time`.

```
<?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'time',array('Past'=>'Past','Future'=>'Future'),array('onclick' => 'this.form.submit()')); ?>
```

Now, coming to my **question** -
By using [CJuiDatePicker](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/578/date-picker-by-examples/#hh0) I created two filters for date which is in `datetime` format.

```
<?php
$dateisOn = $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
            // 'model'=>$model,
            'name' => 'Event[date_first]',
            'language' => 'id',
            'value' => $model->time,
            // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
            'options' => array(
                'showAnim' => 'slide',
                'dateFormat' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                'changeMonth' => 'true',
                'changeYear' => 'true',
                'constrainInput' => 'false',
            ),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'style' => 'height:20px;width:70px;',
            ),
// DONT FORGET TO ADD TRUE this will create the datepicker return as string
                ), true) . '<br> To <br> ' . $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
            // 'model'=>$model,
            'name' => 'Event[date_last]',
            'language' => 'id',
            'value' => $model->time,
            // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
            'options' => array(
                'showAnim' => 'slide',
                'dateFormat' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                'changeMonth' => 'true',
                'changeYear' => 'true',
                'constrainInput' => 'false',
            ),
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'style' => 'height:20px;width:70px',
            ),
// DONT FORGET TO ADD TRUE this will create the datepicker return as string
                ), true);
?>
```

In GridView I got two filters, one for `startdate` and `enddate`. I added the following code in gridview.

```
<?php     array(
            'name'=>'time',
            'filter'=>$dateisOn,
            'value'=>'$data->time',
            ),         
?>
```

Now, my questions are -

1. How can I get the dates filtered when I click on Past button which is going to filter all the dates less than current date(datetime format).
2. How can I get the dates filtered when I click on Future button which is going to filter all the dates greater than current date(datetime format).
3. CJuiDatePicker works on only single click and after that it disappears, the page has to refreshed again to get it back.

Comment: By word "Disappears" you mean that whole widget disappears as it was never there?

Comment: You creating radiobuttons, not buttons. Anyway, you should add eventlisteners on `change` event on that radiobuttonlist and submit data from form with radiobuttons and gridview filter.
To filter data you should specify search rules in your data source (e.g. `model->search()`)